# Filtro de datas utilizando o mês

Tags: php, mysql, combobox

prezado(a)s

É o seguinte, tenho um formulário onde faço alguns filtros/buscas que exibe os resultados em uma tabela, porém preciso filtrar as datas pelo mês que fazem parte da própria data, tipo mes 01,mes 02 etc, até o momento não obtive exito, alguém pode me da um norte?

crie uma combobox onde passo os meses, na consulta tentei a seguinte implementação AND MONTH (data_processo) LIKE '$parametro_data%',

```html
<form>
      <div class="col-sm-2" style="">
           <select name="parametro_data" id="data" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">MÊS</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="09">09</option>
                        <option value="08">08</option>
                        <option value="07">07</option>
                        <option value="06">06</option>
                        <option value="05">05</option>
                        <option value="04">04</option>
                        <option value="03">03</option>
                        <option value="02">02</option>
                        <option value="01">01</option>  
                    </select>
                </div>
        </form>


        <?php
        $parametro_data = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "parametro_data");
        
        $sql = "SELECT tb_processo.codigo_processo,tb_processo.data_processo 
        FROM 
        tb_processo
        WHERE MONTH (data_processo) LIKE '$parametro_data%');
```

porem não é retornado nenhum resultado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O operador LIKE se aplica a campos do tipo texto. Como o seu campo é data, e você quer filtrar apenas um mês, tente fazer da seguinte forma:

```
 $sql = "SELECT tb_processo.codigo_processo,tb_processo.data_processo 
        FROM 
        tb_processo
        WHERE MONTH (data_processo) = " . $parametro_data;
```

Caso seja necessário filtrar mais de 1 mês, você pode fazer algo assim:

```
 $sql = "SELECT tb_processo.codigo_processo,tb_processo.data_processo 
    FROM 
    tb_processo
    WHERE MONTH (data_processo) in (1,2,3)";
```

Comment: Obrigado Bins, valeu pela força